# populating mapOverlay

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Does anyone know of any tutorials on populating a Mapview using an overlay at a specific point? e.g adding a marker at a specific lat / lng on your mapview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this mobiforge tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android), works great. One of the first results in google ;)